# Criando Function PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql

Estou com um problema ao criar uma *function*. Eu estou puxando os parâmetros dela da minha aplicação java, o problema ocorre ao puxar os parâmetros ( `variavel1`, e `variavel2`) porque elas estão vindo da aplicação como texto. Ocorre um erro quando vou comparar com um tipo numérico na *query* dentro da função:

```
 inner JOIN prestadores m on m.id= variavel1
```

#### Erro

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = text LINE 12: ...
>   inner JOIN prestadores m on m.id= variavel1...

Justamente porque o `id` do prestadores é *integer* !!!!

Já tentei fazer *esse cast* dentro da função:

```
inner JOIN prestadores m on m.id= variavel1::integer
```

Mas aí ele da erro também porque nao reconhece o `c.id_medico` que preciso passar por parâmetro. Não posso alterar a função para receber somente números pois pode haver casos na minha aplicação que usam outros ids de outras tabelas (com outros tipos):

#### Função

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.rel_repasse_solicitante(data1 date, data2 date, idcorp integer, titulo text, variavel1 text, variavel2 text)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS

$BODY$
BEGIN
 RETURN QUERY select   data1 as inicio, 
                        data2 as fim, p.nome as paciente, 
                        titulo as titulo, pl.nome as plano, m.nome as medico,
                        c.data_prescricao AS data_atendimento, c.codigo_tiss, 
                        c.codigo_tiss || ' - ' || t.descri as descri, c.conta, c.id_pagamento_medico, c.guia, 
                        5 as taxa, c.quant, (c.quant * 5) as valor_total 
                        from contas c 
                        inner join cadastro_pessoa_fisica p on p.id=c.id_paciente 
                        left outer join pagamento_medico pg on pg.id=c.id_pagamento_medico 
                        inner join plano_convenio pl on pl.id=c.id_plano 
                        inner join guia_consulta_tiss g on g.id=c.guia 
                        inner JOIN prestadores m on m.id= variavel1
                        inner JOIN prestadores co on co.id=pl.id_convenio 
                        inner join empresas e on e.id=co.id_empresa 
                        left outer join tabela_amb t on t.codigo=c.codigo_tiss and
                        variavel2 and t.ativo=true and t.id_tabela=pl.id_tabela_amb 
                        where p.id_corp=idcorp and 
                        c.data_prescricao >=data1 
                        and c.data_prescricao <=data2 
                        and (c.tipo=3 or c.tipo > 4) and c.codigo_tiss != '50101010' 
                        and c.codigo_tiss != '60101010' and c.codigo_tiss != '20010010' 
                        and c.codigo_tiss != '10101012' and c.codigo_tiss != '20101012' 
                        and c.codigo_tiss != '30101012' and c.codigo_tiss != '00010014' 
                        and c.codigo_tiss != '40101010' and c.codigo_tiss != '20010010' 
                        and c.codigo_tiss != '20101011' 
                        order by pg.id, m.nome, c.data_prescricao, paciente;
 RETURN;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION public.rel_repasse_solicitante(data1 date, data2 date, idcorp integer, titulo text, variavel1 text, variavel2 text)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

#### Execução da função

```
select * from rel_repasse_solicitante('2016-01-01', '2016-12-09',1, 
'PREVIA DO REPASSE DE BONUS PARA O MEDICO EXECUTANTE', 'c.id_medico', 
' c.data_prescricao >=2016-01-01 and c.data_prescricao <=2016-12-09 and 
c.data_recebimento notnull and c.id_pagamento_medico isnull and c.ativo=true') as 
(inicio date, fim date, paciente character varying, titulo text, plano character varying, 
medico character varying, data_atendimento date, codigo_tiss character varying, descri text, conta integer, 
id_pagamento_medico integer, guia integer, taxa integer, quant numeric, valor_total numeric)
```

#### Chamada do Java

```
if (Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("tipo")) == 191 || Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("tipo")) == 192 || Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("tipo")) == 193) {
                relatorio = caminho + "Rel_Repasse_Solicitante.jasper";
                resportStream = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(relatorio);
                String titulo="REPASSE DE BONUS";
                String m = "c.id_medico";
                if (Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("tipo")) == 192) {
                        titulo = "PREVIA DO REPASSE DE BONUS";
                    }else
                    if (Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("tipo")) == 193) {
                        titulo = "PENDENCIA DE REPASSE DE BONUS";
                    }

                if(request.getParameter("tipomedico").equals("1")){
                        //opcao para medico executante
                        titulo+=" PARA O MEDICO EXECUTANTE";

                    }else
                     if(request.getParameter("tipomedico").equals("2")){
                        //opcao para medico solicitante
                        titulo+=" PARA O MEDICO SOLICITANTE";
                        m= "g.id_solicitante";
                    }else{
                         //opcao para medico autorizador
                         titulo+=" PARA O MEDICO AUTORIZADOR";
                          m= "g.id_medico_autorizador";
                     } 
                conexao.executeSQL("select * from rel_repasse_solicitante("
                        + "'"+request.getParameter("datainicial")+"', "
                        + "'"+request.getParameter("datafinal")+"',"+idcorp+", "
                        + "'"+titulo+"', '"+m+"', '"+request.getParameter("tipo")+"',"
                        + ""+request.getParameter("idmedico")+") as "
                        + "(inicio date, fim date, paciente character varying, "
                        + "titulo text, plano character varying, "
                        + "medico character varying, data_atendimento date, "
                        + "codigo_tiss character varying, descri text, "
                        + "conta integer, id_pagamento_medico integer, "
                        + "guia integer, taxa integer, quant numeric, "
                        + "valor_total numeric)");
```

No caso a variável `m` está recebendo o `ID` da tabela que vou referenciar no banco, de acordo com o que o usuário está escolhendo...

Comment: Coloca aí sua chamada do java

Comment: Arthur, fiz umas modificações na sua pergunta (fique a vontade de pedir para reverter se eu não consegui capturar direito o que você queria). Que tal usar o [pseudo-tipo `any`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-pseudo.html) e `java.lang.Object` do lado do Java? Essa seria a forma mais "genérica" de implementar esse tipo de coisa.

Comment: Vou verificar, obrigado, mas se alguém souber um metodo mais facil. Tive que fazer um gato para rodar a Function desta forma    "   inner JOIN prestadores m on m.id=case when vm='c.id_medico' then c.id_medico --variavel m
       when vm='g.id_solicitante' then g.id_solicitante 
       when vm='g.id_medico_autorizador' then g.id_medico_autorizador end   " ,  mas seria bom sem usar essas clausulas Case né kkk só passando a  variavel .

Comment: Eu tomaria cuidado com esse código. Essas concatenações do lado do Java são portas para *SQL Injection*. Eu usaria um [`CallableStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html). Do lado do PostgreSQL acho bem difícil que você consiga escapar de um comando [`EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) já que o que você parece estar querendo fazer é concatenar condições dinâmicas em uma *query*...

Comment: Talvez valha a pena repensar a implementação. Isso está com uma cara forte de *criteria query*. Talvez uma biblioteca como [SqlBuilder](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/sqlbuilder/) te atenda menor, possivelmente até eliminando a necessidade da `FUNCTION`.

Comment: Não entendi direito, você está fazendo uma chamada de function do postgreSQL no java?
Pelo que estou vendo você só está executando um comando. E para isso você poderia usar preparedStatement.
Você pode ver mas aqui: http://www.devmedia.com.br/aprendendo-java-com-jdbc/29116

Você pode obter ajudar aqui também: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17435060/call-a-stored-function-on-postgres-from-java

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o CallableStatement.

```
CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(" { call function( ?, ?, ? ) } ");
statement.setInt(1, value);
statement.setInt(2, value);
statement.setInt(3, value);
statement.execute();
statement.close();
```

referência: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17435060/call-a-stored-function-on-postgres-from-java